# update_post_meta is Updating with two page id

Tags: functions, hooks

I am writing a code to count the number of views of post.
For that I am using update_post_meta and passing appropriate parameter.

I am calling a function on add_action('wp', 'function_name'); in functions.php.

My problem is, whenever I am loading the page in Chrome, it works fine.
But when I am loading the page in Mozilla Firefox, it is updating the page view counts for two/three page's id in wp_postmeta table.

Should I use some other action hook?? If yes, which one?
Can anyone tell me, what the issue is??

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably Firefox prefetching pages, which it can do based on the `rel` attribute of links (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18156967/664741). You could alter these links to remove eg `rel="next"`, or you could detect Firefox prefetching by checking the headers sent:

```
if ( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_MOZ'] ) || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_MOZ'] != 'prefetch' ) {
    add_action( 'wp', 'function_name' );
}
```